# file upload via Rcurl

Tags: r, centos7, rcurl

I try to upload a png to my server, but it tells me that it can't change to the directory. What is the convention for the public_html in Centos. Consequently it mentions "Server denied you to change to the given directory"

```
ftpUpload(what = "http://skiweather.eu:8787/files/R/devel/PLOTS/snowalert_today_0.png",
          to = "ftp://149.210.237.45/home/skiweather/domains/skiweather.eu/public_html/snowalert_today.png",
          verbose = TRUE,
          userpwd = "skw:Si24343!", prequote="CWD  /home/skiweather/domains/skiweather.eu/public_html/")
```